Irreducible topological space definition

A topological space X is called reducible if $X=X_1 \cup X_2$ for closed subsets $X_1, X_2\subsetneq X$. And $X$ is irreducible if $X \neq \emptyset$ and X is not reducible.

This is the definition I found for reducible and irreducible topological spaces when I was reading Commutative Algebra. Also $\mathbb{C}$ with Zariski topology is irreducible (In fact every $n$ dimensional affine space over an algebraically closed field $k$ is irreducible with Zariski topology) since $I(\mathbb{C}^n)=(0)$ and it is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. Also I reckon that $\mathbb{C}$ is a Noetherian topological space. But all of these doesn't add up when it comes to the following theorem

Every Noetherian topological space $X\neq \emptyset$ is a finite union of irreducible closed subsets of $X$ $\implies X=X_1 \cup \dots X_r$ where $X_i$'s are closed subsets of $X$.

Doesn't that make $X$ reducible as per definition? Actually isn't it making every Noetherian topological space reducible? Then $\mathbb{C}$ should be reducible as well which is not true when equipped with Zariski topology. What am I missing/done wrong here?
Edit: Also the proof of this theorem is by method of contradiction and the assumption that $X$ is not a finite union of irreducible closed subsets leads to the conclusion $X$ is reducible. But what if $X$ is a union of infinite irreducible closed sets. How can one say that $X$ is reducible from that ?

Note that $r$ can be equal to $1$. Just like every integer $\geq 2$ having a prime factorization doesn't imply that every such integer is composite. It might be prime, and then it has just one factor in the decomposition.

Thanks for that. I didn't consider that. @Mark

It looks like you changed your question to a fairly different one after Mark provided an answer in the comments. The guidelines suggest you should ask one question per post. Also, I think it would be helpful to provide the references you are using, if possible, because it might help to be able to look at the proof you are following. There's a feature which allows you to include explicit references.
